# Change aspect ratio of inset axes from `zoomed_inset_axes`

Tags: matplotlib

How do i change the dimensions of an inset `axes` object?

I'm creating a plot like this:

[image]

I would like the inset to be wider, the `zoomed_inset_axes` method defaults to the same aspect ratio as the underlying data (sensibly i guess), but it seems to resist any attempt I make to change it...

I'm using it like this:

```
axins.axis(args.inset_extent)
os = axins.get_position()
pos = [pos.x0, pos.y0,  pos.width * 2, pos.height]
axins.set_position(pos)
```

I've tried the `which` kwarg of [set_position](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_position) too, and that also appears to do nothing.

**How can i set the position of the inset plot, and more importantly change it's aspect ratio?**

It's part of a reasonably long plotting script, the full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/4zwCCeXJ), and a couple of example basis sets to try it are here: [6-31G.dat](http://pastebin.com/kHvyvd2V) and [3-21G.dat](http://pastebin.com/ZyydHEsY).

Just download them into their own dir, and put the basis set files in a dir called `basis_sets`, and then use the command:

```sh
./basis_sets.py -r -2 2 -b 6-31G 3-21G -a C --inset --inset-zoom 6 --inset-extent -0.03 0.03 6.7 7.7
```

(`./basis_sets.py --help` prints out usage guide)

Answer (score 7):

So i found another function in there, just called [`inset_axes`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#insetlocator).

It's used a little differently, but does exactly what i want, and the `mark_inset` helper function still works too, which is nice.

So now i have:

```
ax = inset_axes(ax, width=XX, height=XX, loc=XX)
ax.axis([x0, x1, y0, y1])
```

istead of the zoom one and it is much more flexible.

Comment: Here is the up-to-date reference for [matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html).